# How can a Gradle plugin access its own files?

Tags: gradle

My custom Gradle plugin contains files which it wants to copy into the output produced by the build that uses my plugin.

How can my plugin access its own files?

All variables I have tried always refer to the project that applied my plugin, but not to the contents of the plugin.

Comment: Where are the files placed? Could You please provide sample code?

Comment: What does it mean *contained in the plugin itself*?

Comment: @Opal Well, a Gradle plugin is a JAR file that contains files. People download the plugin and apply it in their build script. I want the plugin to read its own files, anything that is contained in the plugin JAR.

Comment: It seems that You could read the files via `getClass().getResource()`.

Comment: @Opal Works! Thank you! Please consider posting as an answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Added an answer. This is why I was asking what it does exactly mean *contained in the plugin itself* ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that if files are located in the jar itself it can be loaded via the following construct:

```
getClass().getResource("resourceName")
```